# Variable scope in S3 generics

Tags: r, scope, r-s3

I have the following snippet:

```
y <- 1
g <- function(x) {
  y <- 2
  UseMethod("g")
}
g.numeric <- function(x) y
g(10)
# [1] 2
```

I do not understand, why it is possible to have access to `y` in `g.numeric <- function(x) y`. To my understanding y's scope is just within the definition of the generic `(g <- ...)`. Could anyone explain to me, how that is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description of this behavior can be found in the `?UseMethod` help page

> UseMethod creates a new function call with arguments matched as they came in to the generic. Any local variables defined before the call to UseMethod are retained

Thus any local variables defined in the function calling `UseMethod` are passed along to the next function as local variables. You can see this with

```
g.numeric <- function(x) ls()  #lists all variables in current environment
g(10)
# [1] "x" "y"
g.numeric(10)
# [1] "x"
```

Comment: Does `UseMethod` even come into play here? E.g.: `x <- "global"; test <- function() x; test(); rm(x); test()` Doesn't R just search in parent environments if it can't find the object in a local scope?

Comment: @thelatemail Notice that the value of `y` is changing in the `g()` function and this is the value that's passed along, not the value in the global environment. R will normally search parent environments where the function was *defined*, not *called*. This particular behavior is unique to `UseMethod`.

Comment: I just don't understand why `y` would ever be `1` when calling `g(numeric())` as `y <- 2` sets it inside that function. `g.numeric(numeric())` similarly doesn't change `y`.

Comment: @thelatemail try: `y <- 1; g <- function(x) {y <- 2;g.numeric(x)}; g.numeric <- function(x) y; g(10); #[1] 1`. Notice the only difference is changing `UseMethod("g")` to `g.numeric(x)` which you might expect to be the same (and they are not).

Comment: Right - that's a nice example. Sooooo.... because `g.numeric` gets defined in a global environment, it goes hunting in the global rather than local space first? I think I have it through my thick skull now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for great explanation and the example!